# Which alternatives to bundling lots instructional videos into a fitness app are there?

Tags: ios, performance, video

We would like to bundle lots of short instructional videos with our upcoming iOS fitness app. I have concerns about app bundle size; but then again, games tend to become large, too. So I wonder both about alternatives & reasons to consider them in the first place (e.g. download size of the app).

Which alternatives exist to bundling video data with the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctietze, You should use streaming of course. App size will effect your downloads, don't forget most of the people using 16GB iOS devices. In game industry they even download intro videos after you download, when you first open the app. Hope this helps. Wishing you (and company) great success with your new application.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying I don't even need to stream on every view, but could download the videos once before needed, so the app bundle stays small. Sounds good.

Comment: Actually you need to stream in every view, I just want to say, if you have another videos in application like a tutorial to show people how to use application (maybe), for this type of assets you can use "first open download". All the others can be start streaming after user tap of them, you don't need to download anything because this is streaming, it's downloading only part you're watching (like few seconds), think how youtube application streaming or when you open video in wired.com's iOS application it's streaming instantly, not downloading before. Check Amazon S3 for streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I would expect 100% streaming to be ennerving when you're not on wi-fi. Maybe a few core videos can be cached instead for better UX. We'll see!